# How can I set a chart to always show description by default

Tags: apache-superset

If I define a description for a chart I can manually use the "Toggle chart description" to show the description for a given chart.

How can I define on a per chart or global basis if the description should be visible de default?

[image: definition of name and description for the chart]

[image: default presentation of the chart without description and toggle using context menu]

[image: chart with description - desired result by default]

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the slice id for the chart you want to keep expanded.
Then in Dashboard settings, go to advance and you'll have something like this.

```
{
   "timed_refresh_immune_slices": [],
   "expanded_slices": {"36": true},
   "refresh_frequency": 0,
   "default_filters": "{}",
   "color_scheme": null
}
```

Put your chart/slice id in `expanded_slices`, set it to `true` and it will always be displayed.

Comment: How do you find the slice id for a chart?

Comment: When you click Edit Chart, the last value in the URL on the edit chart page will be the chart's slice ID, e.g., `&slice_id=788`